# Como abrir modal bootstrap ao abrir um determinada página?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal

Como fazer aparecer um modal ao abrir a página?

Estou usando este código:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <img src="assets/images/carousel/banner02.png" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: não entendi ? ..

Comment: Preciso que um modal apareça quando abro um site

Comment: a sua pergunta não fala tudo, esse modal é bootstrap?

Comment: Isso é bootstrap

Comment: versão do boostrap? coloque isso na pergunta! o que você tentou?

Comment: É a versão 5.0.2

Comment: Só consegui fazer ele com box ao clicar

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Abra o [modal BootStrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal) com `Javascript` como está em sua [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript), *siga o exemplo*:

Declare a parte do `javascript` que é responsável em chamar o modal pela seu `id` nome configurado no modal e após criar a instância desse modal chame o comando `show();` para mostrar o `modal` na tela. Também na página deve existir o [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) para utilizar a função inicial `$(function() { ... });`.

Código que chama:

```js
$(function() { // vai executar com o DOM estiver pronto.
   var staticBackdrop = document.getElementById('staticBackdrop'); // ref modal
   var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(staticBackdrop); // cria instância do modal
   myModal.show(); // chama o comando show para abrir
});
```

Código total com exemplo funcional:

```js
$(function() {
   var staticBackdrop = document.getElementById('staticBackdrop');
   var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(staticBackdrop);
   myModal.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```